# Best way to "cut" a connection on a pcb

Tags: pcb, components, component-selection, trace

Imagine you have some traces on a PCB, that connect from point A to point B.
I would like to have control over that connection. I want to be able to enable/disable the connection from a distance (microcontroller included).

What is the best way to enable/disable the connection? Transistors, switches.... Something that the microcontroller can control, and that then can control the connection to the trace...

What is the best component to use for this purpose?

Comment: Depends what kind of signal this "connection" is supposed to conduct.

Comment: There is no best way unless it is known what the connection carries. 16A at mains voltage, 5 GHz wireless LAN antenna signal, or something else?

Comment: @EugeneSh. high speed data transfer connection.

Comment: @Justme It is high speed data transfer.

Comment: What kind of data? Digital? Analog? How "high speed"?

Comment: @user1584421 we still don't know what "high speed data transfer" means to you.

Comment: Data connection/transfer between microcontrollers. I am not hiding something. This is all i know so far as well.... That's why i am searching for a component.

Comment: If you don't know what kind of data connection it is, you can't know what's the best component for it.

Comment: Well, you will need to know it. But anyway, "breaking" such a communication line by some separate component seem to be a radical solution. Microcontrollers can orderly stop the communication and even "disconnect" from the line by setting the pin to tri-state.

Comment: Looks like  an [XY-Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks! Although it is the first time i hear of "tri-state" i will look it up.

Comment: Better look for "high impedance" (same thing more or less), as tri-state will lead you to weird results...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing anything about the signal, I'll say the most universal solution is an analog transmission gate.  The signals must remain within the range of the power supply to the T-gate.

Depending on the signal characteristics, there are several simpler/cheaper options available.  Can you describe the signals to be on these traces?

Comment: Thanks. They are high speed data transfer digital signals.

Comment: If you have supplies outside of the signal range, you could use MOSFETs.  You just have to drive the gate at least one gate threshold above/below the max/min value of the signal (depending on type).

Comment: Thanks. Since i don't know much about MOSFETS... What i should i research? I mean a good search term. "MOSFETS as a switch"?

Comment: @user1584421 You need to know what you are switching, then decide what is a good way of switching that. MOSFETs might be completely unusable for your switching purposes because even you don't know what you are switching.

Comment: @Justme i am enabling/disabling the data between two microcontrollers.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific - are we talking about spi? If so, what bit rate? i2C? Or 8 bit parallel data? If you want a precise answer, give us precise information. Nevertheless, you might use multiplexers like 74HC157 or tristate buffers like 74HC244 or 245. These are good to probably 30MHz. If you need faster there are similar devices that are higher speed and can do voltage level translation.

Comment: @user1584421 If you don't know whether it is USB, Ethernet, PCIE, CAN, or something else, nobody can point you to a best or even the an adequate component that might be compatible with it.

Comment: @Justme It is data transmission, so USB and Ethernet are possible candidates. Two of the most possible ones.

Comment: USB and Ethernet require very different solutions. Short of using relays, there is not really a generic solution. For USB, it would be uncommon to switch the signals apart from plugging it in and out. If you wanted multiple USB connections, you'd probably use a hub. Similarly with ethernet, but you'd probably use an ethernet switch chip. You might want to give us a concrete example of what you want to do.